# load usercontrol with jquery with handler

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, webusercontrol, dynamic-usercontrols

i want loading dynamically usercontrol with jquery. first i create this  UserControl in root website :

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="UcProduct.ascx.cs" Inherits="UC_UcProduct" %>
<p> Mohsen</p>
```

after that i create .aspx page and write this code for loading UserControl

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <script src="Script/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: 'B Mitra', Tahoma, Arial;
            font-size: 20px;
            text-shadow: 4px 4px 4px #aaa;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        $(function () {

            $("#UserCtrl").load("UcProduct.ascx");

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="UserCtrl">
            111
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Thereafter i create class in App_code

```
namespace Eshop
{

    public class jQueryHandler : IHttpHandler
    {
        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            using (var dummyPage = new Page())
            {
                dummyPage.Controls.Add(GetControl(context));
                context.Server.Execute(dummyPage, context.Response.Output, true);
            }
        }
        private Control GetControl(HttpContext context)
        {
            // URL path given by load(fn) method on click of button
            string strPath = context.Request.Url.LocalPath;
            UserControl userctrl = null;
            using (var dummyPage = new Page())
            {
                userctrl = dummyPage.LoadControl(strPath) as UserControl;
            }
            // Loaded user control is returned
            return userctrl;
        }
    }
}
```

finally add this section in web.config

```
<httpHandlers>
      <add verb="*" path="*.ascx" type="Eshop.jQueryHandler,App_Code" />
    </httpHandlers>
```

when run Default.aspx page don't load userControl , and when check with firebug i get this message
[image]
please help me. thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it is a problem of file extension. The server is not allowed to serve ascx files.

You may try :

```
<httpHandlers>
   <remove verb="*" path="*.ascx"/>
  <add verb="*" path="*.ascx" type="Eshop.jQueryHandler,App_Code" />
</httpHandlers>
```

or

declaring the handler for `path="*.myascx"`, then load the corresponding `.ascx` in the handler (this would change your ajax calls urls)